# Returning multiple values after insert

Tags: oracle, plsql

I got this 'Message' table.

```
CREATE TABLE message (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    user_id INT NOT NULL REFERENCES users (id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    category_id INT NOT NULL REFERENCES category (id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    text VARCHAR2(4000),
    media VARCHAR2(500),
    creation_date DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE
);

CREATE SEQUENCE message_seq;
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER message_bir 
BEFORE INSERT ON message
FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
  SELECT message_seq.NEXTVAL
  INTO   :new.id
  FROM   dual;
END;
```

After i insert something i need the last inserted id and the date.

```
INSERT INTO message (user_id, category_id, media)
VALUES (1, 1, 'fdsfsd')
RETURNING id INTO :last_insert_id
```

The above gives me the last inserted id, but like i said i also need the creation_date. I dont want to do a select query after...

Is there a way to get 2 values back after run an insert?

Comment: if you want to display insert date soon after insert then it will be always current date. Why don't you just display current date then ?

Comment: Accrding to the docs, you should be able to write: `RETURNING id, creation_date INTO :last_insert_id, :last_creation_date`. See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/returninginto_clause.htm

Comment: Because the server date could be different from the client date!

Comment: @HellmarBecker, make your comment into an answer. It's OK to do it that way.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can write:

```
RETURNING id, creation_date INTO :last_insert_id, :last_creation_date.
```

See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/returninginto_clause.htm